# Merge Large Files in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job with 3 main steps:

- **Step 1**: reads, process, and write to tmp xml files (filesize? +500Mb each).
- **Step 2**: reads the tmp files and write to a single one file (with header and footer callback).
- **Step 3**: delete tmp files.

The issue I'm facing is that my job fails at step 2 with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

And here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.write(FlatFileItemWriter.java:267)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor683.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
```

Also here's the configuration of the second step:

```
<!-- STEP 2 -->
    <!-- READER -->
    <bean id="multiResourceItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step" >
        <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['PATH_OUT_REP'] + '/tmp/*'}"/>
        <property name="delegate">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
                <property name="lineMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughLineMapper"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- WRITER -->
    <bean id="flatFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step" >
        <property name="resource" value="file:#{jobParameters['PATH_OUT_REP'] + '/' + jobParameters['CURRENT.FILENAME']}"/>
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator"/>
        </property>
        <property name="headerCallback" ref="flatFileItemWriterHeaderCallback"/>
        <property name="footerCallback" ref="flatFileItemWriterFooterCallback"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="flatFileItemWriterHeaderCallback" class="com.salimrahmani.job.writer.FlatFileItemWriterHeaderCallback"/>
    <bean id="flatFileItemWriterFooterCallback" class="com.salimrahmani.job.writer.FlatFileItemWriterFooterCallback"/>
```

I've read that using multiresourcepartitioner I could use multithreading but i don't see how is this related to memory space. Also, preferably not increase the JVM heap size.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You should consider using the Java Stream API for your job.

Comment: Hi @McPringle thank you for your comment! Can you elaborate more please ? or point me to some articles! thanks!

Comment: Streams are a feature introduced with Java 8 which was further improved with almost every version. As a Java developer, you should definitely know how to work with streams. I highly recommend an article from Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams You should read an older article of the same author first: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams-introduction

With the Java Stream API you can accomplish your tasks with single or multiple threads and a low memory footprint (no need to have all data in memory at the same time).

Comment: haha thanks ! i know what java streams are but do you mean like creating an implementation of ItemReader and IteamWriter to use Java Streams API ?!